# How to re-arrange array position coming from API in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

```js
props: {
    groups: Array,
  },
  computed: {
    groups: function(arr) {
      alert('hi')
    }
  },
```

```html
<div v-for="(item, index) in groups" :key="item.id" :id="item.id" class="group-name" @click="isOnlySelected ? null : $emit('setSelectedItem', item.id)">
</div>
```

How to re-arrange array position coming from API in frontend?

I am able to display all the value from api to frontend. But i need to add some condition like to sort the array value. example( i need to change the array[6] position to array[1] position.

Comment: Use a computed property that returns the sorted array based on whatever criteria you have set.

Comment: @Terry I have taken computed property. But not sure how to take the sorted array....Can you please suggest me with some code

Comment: It's not possible to help without seeing a sample of your array data? You can leave out all the fetch logic in your code since they are not relevant to your question at all. Please see how to create an [mcve].

Comment: @Terry I have added the response array data. is it fine?.....I am not sure where I am missing the logic???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one option would be using a computed property that sorts/swaps your array. Then, you use that computed property in your v-for.

```js
computed: {
  rearrangeDataset () {
    if (Array.isArray(this.dataset) && this.dataset.length) {
      // Do your sorting or swapping. Always return a value in a computed property.
      let tmp = this.dataset[2]
      this.dataset[2] = this.dataset[0]
      this.dataset[0] = tmp
      return this.dataset
    } else {
      return []
    }
  }
}
```

Then use this computed in your v-for:

```js
<div v-for="(item, index) in rearrangeDataset" :key="item.id" :id="item.id" class="group-name" @click="isOnlySelected ? null : $emit('setSelectedItem', item.id)">
</div>
```

I see that you use this dataset in a handler (its ID), so I think it is best to mutate your dataset in a computed property and return that same dataset.

I've created an example at codepen for you: https://codepen.io/LucasFer/pen/oNewOwv

Notice that you could also approach this with `watch`.

Comment: excellent example. Very helpful..... :)